# appending/joining two recarrays created by mlab.csv2rec(file)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to append three recarrays that I created using `mlab.csv2rec(file)`

The recarray has several fields for example:

```
data = mlab.csv2rec(fd)
data2 = mlab.csv2rec(fd2)

data.temp, data.volt, data.chan, data.power
data2.temp, data2.volt, data2.chan, data2.power
```

And the two recarrays are unique. I have tried using the `rec_join` function but without any success in the following manner:

```
data3 = mlab.rec_join([i for i, j in data.dtype.descr],data,data2)
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Think I know the solution to this.

I used the `np.hstack()` function to stack them first.

```
data3 = np.hstack((data,data2))
```

Then I typecast it using the following function:

```
data4 = data3.view(np.recarray)
```